# What is the meaning of x in this formula? (Kernel smoothing)

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to implement Kernel smoothing in MATLAB.The code is implemented from Alpaydin's textbook on Machine Learning.

[image]

In the first for-loop I'm calculating the 'sum of k of this expression' from the second formula in the textbook. The problem is I'm not sure what is x. As I understood xt are my data points right? I've seen (unfortunately I lost the link) that x is the half of the bin. Is this correct? Any hint would be helpful. Just in case I'm attaching part of my code, where 'input' is the x.

```
for i=1:size(data,1)
SumKernel(i,1)=(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((((input(i,1)-data(i,1))/binsize)^2)/2));
end;

for i=1:size(data,1)
Kernel_histo(i,1) = (1/(binsize*size(data,1)))*SumKernel(i,1)
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The xt's are your data points.
2. x is your *query* point, i.e., the point whose probability (loosely
       speaking) you are trying to estimate using your data points. Note
       that x and xt have the same dimensions.

See the wiki [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#Definition) for details.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is the position where you want to estimate your smoothed distribution.

**Notation & further explanation:**
Given `x1,...xN` which are data samples from some unknown distribution you want to estimate the underlying *probability density function (pdf)*. So you choose a *bandwith* `h` and a *kernel* `K` and use the *kernel estimator* `p` (parzen window) to estimate the pdf.

**Example in Matlab:**

```
%% get some samples from a random process
xt = [randn(1000,1)-2;2*randn(3000,1)+7];

%% choose kernel K and bandwith h
K = @(u) exp(-u.^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi);
h = 0.4;

%% pdf estimation (implemented in an easy-to-read way)
x = -10:0.001:30;
N = length(xt);
p = 0*x;
for t = 1:N
    p = p + K((x - xt(t))/h);
end
p = p/(N*h);

%% plot result
figure;
hold on;
histBinWidth = 1;
[histY,histX] = hist(xt,-10:histBinWidth:30);
bar(histX,histY/(N*histBinWidth));
plot(x,p,'r');
```

[image: example result]